# Why do group policies block scheduled task script?

Tags: windows, group-policy, scheduled-tasks

I created a scheduled task that launches a powershell script using the local administrator account. I need this task to be executed even when no one is connected to a session, hence I chose the option "run whether the user is logged on or not". In this script, I am using the pnputil action to install a usb stick on the machine. I previoulsy set the local policies in order to block installation of usb devices (Prevent installation of devices not described by other policy settings) but I allowed the administrators to bypass this policy (Allow administrators to override Device Installation Restrictions).

However, when I run the task, I get the following error : "Unable to install driver package on matching devices : The installation of this device is forbidden by system policy.". The task runs well when I choose " Run only when the user is logged on".

Does somebody have an explanation or a solution ?

Comment: Are you an Administrator on the Active Directory domain?  As for the reason you are getting this message, you have a group policy that is specifically enabled, to prevent this type of action.  I am guessing you allows domain Administrator, not local Administrators on the machine, when dealing with a Active Directory those are two separate things.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake I meant "local policies " and not "group policies " I edited my post. I am the local administrator of the machine and there is no Active Directory. I allowed the "admlocal" user to run the task.